# Chunk size sent to client affects the file completeness

Tags: android, c++, qt, networking, tcp

Update: The problem must be on the Android side, not Qt.

The problem is simply I can't send more than 1000 bytes (correctly) from Windows (via Qt) to Android. Here I post full information:

Code in Qt Creator (Windows side):

```
QFile inputFile(fileInfo->absoluteFilePath());
QByteArray read;
inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
int size = 0;
while(1){
    read.clear();
    read = inputFile.read(1000);
    qDebug()<< "Read : " <<read.size();
    size += read.size();
    if(read.size() == 0){
        break;
    }
    QByteArray toWrite(read);
    newSocket->write(toWrite);
    newSocket->flush();
    newSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
    this->sleep(1);
}
inputFile.close();
qDebug()<<"Transfer Done! " << size << " bytes";}
```

Java code (Android side):

```
DataOutputStream dos;
DataInputStream dis;
Socket s;
s = new Socket("192.168.137.1",8080);
dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
while(true){
    if(dis.available() > 0 ) {
    int chunkSize = 1000;
    byte[] b = new byte[chunkSize];
    dis.read(b);
    writeToExternalStoragePublic("test.png",b);}
```

The code works pretty good. It even works when I set the chunks size on both sides to 1,000,000, and the data is written to Android, but a lot of the bytes are empty.

Check these photos from hex Workshop data visualizer. Using 1000 as chunkSize in the left and 2000 in right.

[image]
[image]

Here are the files:

[1000ChunkSize](http://www.mediafire.com/file/14rn33l9v9l2w85/hey1000.rar)

[2000ChunkSize](http://www.mediafire.com/file/l4j2d6n6luuhhrj/hey2000.rar/file)

The problem is 1000 is too slow, and it takes a lot of time even for small files though it works. What do you suggest?

A possible problem was the timing on the server side even though it has:

```
waitForBytesWritten();
```

I put

```
this->sleep(1);
```

But it didn't help.

Update: The problem must be on the Android side, not Qt.

Comment: At the very least you should check the values returned by `newSocket->write(toWrite)` and `newSocket->waitForBytesWritten()`.  Having said that, a better model would be to connect/react to the various [`QIODevice` signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#signals) rather than making use of `waitForBytesWritten`.

Comment: @G.M.
Hi and tnx for reply.You actually give me a motive to try it on another platform other than android I wrote some code about client in qt to get the file and save it on the disk.Then on the server I set chunk to 10000000 and sent a 12 mb file and got it fully and clean.(note both server and client run on the same machine).So it seems the problem is in the android side.Anybody have any idea why this happens on android?

Comment: By the way the QIODevice is a different aspect from waitForBytesWritten that I used that's a method on Socket that waits until the bytes are got by the client as far as I know.Reading 2000 bytes from a pc isn't such a big deal to use QIODevice signals as it worked with 10000000.By they way thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Nobody has any problem with getting incomplete data from Tcp on android?